# POST variable is not working in SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, post

I want to pass the value of `login.php` POST variables `$user_key` & `$user_id` to another file `statusdata.php` for which I have used session. In `statusdata.php` I want to use those session variable value in the SQL query of `statusdata.php` file.

To achieve this in `login.php`first I pass the value of POST variable `$_POST["user_key"]` & `$_POST["id"]` to variable `$user_key` & `$user_id` respectively then I pass the value of variable `$user_key` & `$user_id` to session variable `$_SESSION["key"]` & `$_SESSION["id"]` respectively then in `statusdata.php` I call session variable and pass their value in variable `$user_key` & `$user_id` of `statusdata.php`

now the Problem is the value POST variable `$_POST["user_key"]` & `$_POST["id"]` 
are not going to the session to `statusdata.php` but if I give direct values of `$user_key` & `$user_id` in `login.php` then session is working fine but not with POST variable

Again I want to clear that POST variable is getting values from the user through an android app which ask `id` and `key` to authenticate the user from `login.php` and then move to another screen and retrieve data related to entered `id` and `key` using `statusdata.php`

help me to get the value of post variable from `login.php` in session so that it can be used in `statusdata.php`

**`login.php`**

```
<?php

// Start the session
session_start();

require "conn.php";

if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
  $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["id"]);
}

if (isset($_POST["user_key"])) {
  $user_key = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["user_key"]);
}

/* USING THESE DIRECT VALUE IN PLACE OF POST VARIABLE IS WORKING FINE IN SESSION FOR BOTH `login.php` and `statusdata.php` which indicate there is no problem with `statusdata.php` but using POST variable is working fine for `login.php` as authenticating user with `id` and `key` but value of POST variable is not going to session in `statusdata.php`.  

$user_key = "8c9333343c6c4222418edb1d7c9f84d051610526085960a1732c7c3d763fff64ec7f5220998434c896dda243ae777d0fb213f36b9b19f7e4a244d5c993b8dfed";
$user_id = "96";
*/

$mysql_qry = "select * from applications where application_key = '".$user_key."' and application_id = ".$user_id." ;";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $_SESSION["key"] = $user_key;
    $_SESSION["id"] = $user_id;
    echo "Login Success";
} else {
    echo "Login Not Success";   
}

?>
```

**`statusdata.php`**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

require "conn.php";

$user_key = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION["key"])) {
  $user_key = $_SESSION["key"];
}

$user_id = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
  $user_id = $_SESSION["id"];
}

 //creating a query
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT applications.application_id, applications.applicant_name, applications.applicant_aadhaar, applications.applicant_phone, applications.subject, applications.date, applications.description, applications.chairperson_remark, applications.status, officer_accounts.name_of_officer, applications.officer_remark, applications.last_update_on 
FROM applications INNER JOIN officer_accounts ON applications.account_id = officer_accounts.account_id 
WHERE applications.application_id = ? AND applications.application_key = ? ;");

 $stmt->bind_param('ss',$user_id,$user_key);

 //executing the query 
 $stmt->execute();

 //binding results to the query 
 $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $aadhaar, $phone, $subject, $date, $description, $chairperson, $status, $officername, $officerremark, $lastupdate);

 $applications = array(); 

 //traversing through all the result 
 while($stmt->fetch()){
 $temp = array();
 $temp['applications.application_id'] = $id; 
 $temp['applications.applicant_name'] = $name; 
 $temp['applications.applicant_aadhaar'] = $aadhaar; 
 $temp['applications.applicant_phone'] = $phone; 
 $temp['applications.subject'] = $subject;
 $temp['applications.date'] = $date;
 $temp['applications.description'] = $description;
 $temp['applications.chairperson_remark'] = $chairperson;
 $temp['applications.status'] = $status;
 $temp['officer_accounts.name_of_officer'] = $officername;
 $temp['applications.officer_remark'] = $officerremark;
 $temp['applications.last_update_on'] = $lastupdate;
 array_push($applications, $temp);
 }

 //displaying the result in json format 
 echo json_encode($applications);

 // remove all session variables
session_unset(); 

// destroy the session 
session_destroy(); 

?>
```

**NOTE -** I am taking the output of `statusdata.php` SQL query in JSON format as in the end I am extracting it in android.

**Please help me I have tried everything which other similar questions are suggesting but nothing helps**

Comment: error reporting and error checking on the query is a start.

Comment: there's no HTML here neither

Comment: these are PHP script for an android app HTML is not required I have mentioned it already

Comment: in any which case, see my first comment. You're not checking for errors and assume that it works as is.

Comment: I already tried error checking still I am not getting why post variable is not going in statusdata.php

Answer (score 0):

You are having problem in your SQL statement :

```sql
$mysql_qry = "select * from applications where application_key = '".$user_key."' and 
application_id = '".$user_id."' ;";
```

Change this to:

```
$mysql_qry = "select * from applications where application_key = '".$user_key."' and 
application_id = ".$user_id." ;";
```

There is high possibility that the datatype of application_id is integer.
Try running it in the MySQL prompt. It will show you the error if it continues!

Comment: bhai post is working fine for `login.php` what I want to do is use the value of post variable in `statusdata.php`

Comment: Have you checked the SQL statement as I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I think ,your problem is relative to the `if` statement you put before assigning `$_SESSION` values. You may check if you have data in your database corresponding to your query otherwise you won't never get this two session values  on your statusdata.php file.
You can check my answer by assigning `$_SESSION` values without the `if` statement and try to access them again.

Comment: tried in both ways with `if` and without `if` there's no difference the problem is still there

Answer (score -1):

Not a complete answer, but a number of improvements to the scripts:

**login.php:**

```
<?php

// Start the session
session_start();

require "conn.php";

if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
  $user_id = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["id"]);
}

if (isset($_POST["user_key"])) {
  $user_key = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["user_key"]);
}

// check output is as expected
echo "ID:" . $user_id;
echo "Key:" . $user_key;

/* USING THESE DIRECT VALUE IN PLACE OF POST VARIABLE IS WORKING FINE IN SESSION FOR BOTH `login.php` and `statusdata.php` which indicate there is no problem with `statusdata.php` but using POST variable is working fine for `login.php` as authenticating user with `id` and `key` but value of POST variable is not going to session in `statusdata.php`.  

$user_key = "8c9333343c6c4222418edb1d7c9f84d051610526085960a1732c7c3d763fff64ec7f5220998434c896dda243ae777d0fb213f36b9b19f7e4a244d5c993b8dfed";
$user_id = "96";
*/

$mysql_qry = <<<EOF
SELECT * from applications
WHERE application_key = "{$user_key}" and application_id = "{$user_id}"
EOF;

$result = $conn->query($mysql_qry);
if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
    $_SESSION["key"] = $user_key;
    $_SESSION["id"] = $user_id;
    echo "Login Success";
} else {
    echo "Login Not Success";   
}

?>
```

**Statusdata.php:**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

require "conn.php";

// use ternary operators, you can even try ?: operator
$user_key = isset($_SESSION["key"]) ? $_SESSION["key"] : '-1';
$user_id = isset($_SESSION["id"]) ? $_SESSION["id"] : '-1';

// use heredocs for creating a query, they let you format your query neatly
// also try using shorter names 
$query = <<<EOF
SELECT app.application_id, app.applicant_name, 
    app.applicant_aadhaar, app.applicant_phone, 
    app.subject, app.date, app.description, 
    app.chairperson_remark, app.status, 
    oa.name_of_officer, app.officer_remark, 
    app.last_update_on 
FROM applications app
INNER JOIN officer_accounts oa
ON app.account_id = oa.account_id 
WHERE app.application_id = ? AND app.application_key = ? ;
EOF;

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$user_id,$user_key);    
//executing the query 
$stmt->execute();

$applications = array(); 
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// get the rows, use fetch_object or fetch_array
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $applications[] = $row;
}

//displaying the result in json format 
echo json_encode($applications);

// remove all session variables
session_unset(); 

// destroy the session 
session_destroy(); 

?>
```

Comment: try printing the value of $user_key and $user_id in the first script to check that mysqli_escape_string hasn't ruined them. Also echo the values in the second script to see if they're retrieved from $_SESSION okay

Comment: Again the same thing is happening which I mentioned in the post on giving direct value to id and key in login.php then echo $user_key and $user_id is working in both login.php and statusdata.php but using POST in place of giving direct value it worked for login.php but those value is not working in statusdata.php